# How to check can navigate to a destination in Android Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I'm in fragment 'A'. How to check if I can navigate to another fragment like that `findNavController().canNavigate(R.id.action_a_to_b)`? Thank you!

Comment: If you are on fragment 'A', you already know you can navigate to any action you've set on fragment A. What exactly are you trying to do?